# Ajax call to web method not working with content type set to ` application/json; charset=utf-8`

Tags: c#, jquery, c#-2.0

I am trying to pass an array to c# webmethod using jquery ajax.

The code below works fine with C# 4.0 but creates the following exception with c# 2.0.
Anyone knows how to solve this?

### **javascript code**

```
var myarray=new Array();
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "ClientSideMethods.asmx/ArrayTest",
            data: { "values": JSON.stringify(myarray) }
        }
        ).complete(function (data) {
            alert('complete');
        });
```

### **c# code**

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public void ArrayTest(List<string> values)
{
    ...
}
```

### **Exception**(*From firebug)*

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Request format is invalid: application/json; charset=utf-8.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()
```

**edit:**  If I remove `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` the post will work, but the values are not received as an array

**Edit:** when I change content type to `contentType: "application/json` the following error occurs

```
System.InvalidOperationException: AnywhereLogin Web Service method name is not valid.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.Initialize()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocol.SetContext(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)
```

Comment: have you tried just "application/json"?

Comment: @BlackICE Yes, and got another (see the update)

Comment: Please post your web.config.

Comment: @schglurps I dont see the reason. Is there any particular section in web config that prevents posting?

Comment: Yes, the handlers mappings are not the same for the .NET framework 3.5 and 4.0. See this link : http://royaltutorials.com/request-format-is-invalid-application-json-charset-utf-8/

Comment: @schglurps I checked web.config and there is nothing in it related to what is said in the link you provided. i am using c# 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with contentType you've set. It's correct:

```
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

First of all make sure you've valid handler mappings in web.config as shown below:

**Edit:**

```
 <system.web>
  <httpHandlers>
    <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
    <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/>
  </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
```

For more info, check out [this link](http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/ConfiguringASPNETAJAX.aspx#httpHandlers)

Apart from that you must surround data being passed with single/double quotes like below:

```
 data: "{ 'values':" + JSON.stringify(myarray) + "}"
```

Or jQuery will automatically URL encode it. For more info check [this URL](http://encosia.com/3-mistakes-to-avoid-when-using-jquery-with-aspnet-ajax/)

Comment: The code works fine with C# 4.0. But as I said in the question, I am using C# 2.0

Comment: Make sure Web.config entries are there and they're for .net 2.0. Also pass data as I suggested  in my post. you're missing outer "".

Comment: I tried that and now "web service method name is not valid". And when I replace `List<string> values` with `string values` it says again `format is invalid: application/json; charset=utf-8`

Comment: And I couldnot find the correct web.config entries for c# 2.0 to use webmethod

Answer (score 1):

This type of problem may occures some time. ajax call using webmethod working fine from code, but error 500 is displayed when we host on IIS. but don't worry your problem will be resolved by adding following statments in web.config below of system.web :-

```
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="ScriptModule" />
      <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler"     type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    </modules>

    <handlers>
      <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory"/>
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: I tried this and it does not work in my case with a json array. [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29266934/how-to-deserialize-json-single-object-and-array-of-objects-in-asmx-service)